# How to use sqlformat tool with pgAdmin

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, utilities, postgresql, sql

I am trying to add external SQL formatting utility to *pgAdmin*.

There is an option available in pgAdmin3 in `Preferences -> Query tool -> Query editor` called `external formatting utility`

I set up python tool [sqlparse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse). It has command line utility called `sqlformat`. *pgAdmin3* requires external formatting utility to accept `stdin` and `sqlformat --help` says

> Use "-" as FILE to read from stdin.

When I write:

```
sqlformat -
```

... as external formatting utility I am getting error

```
execvp(sqlformat, -) failed with error 2!
```

When I am trying to wrap it in shell script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower -
```

... I am getting error

```
line 2: sqlformat: command not found
```

Nevertheless my shell script works when I am calling it directly:

```
cat in.sql | ~/sqlformat.sh > out.sql
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Is `sqlformat` in your `$PATH` where you run pgAdmin3?  You haven't got any relative pathnames in `$PATH`, I hope?  Did you try using an absolute pathname to `sqlformat` in your script? (i.e. `#!/bin/sh` , `exec /usr/bin/sqlformat ...`, or whatever the right location is)

Comment: BTW error 2 is **ENOENT 2 No such file or directory**, which is consistent with what you get when you go via Bash.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't figure out how to call `sqlformat` directly from *pgAdmin* and why `sqlformat` is unavailable in shell script when it is called via *pgAdmin*, but I've come to a solution.

Find full path to utility using:

```
type -a sqlformat
```

Replace path to utility in shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower -
```

And pass this shell script into *pgAdmin*

Comment: If someone can give better answer - you are welcome, because I don't have any explanations yet

Comment: Did you try using the full pathname in pgAdmin?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a script, you can simply add to the field 'External formatting utility':

```
sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower -
```

It worked for me.

Comment: But the problem is that `squlformat` wasn't found on the search path!  The shell script seems to be merely an attempt to diagnose the problem.